# Bootstrap 3 navigation dropdown stopped working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I haven't changed any code on prod and qa but for some reason my qa collapse nav has stopped working pasting both the code here since I can't figure out what's wrong, I checked the console for error if any but its showing nothing, i even compared both the codes and it shows all is fine.

PROD WORKING

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="../parents/dailyexperience" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">Daily Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../parents/attendance_records" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">Attendance Records</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../parents/photos" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">Photos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../parents/school_info" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">School Info</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">History <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="../parents/dailyexperience_history" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; line-height: 0.4px; !important">Daily Experience</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="../parents/attendance_records_history" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; line-height: 0.4px; !important">Attendance Records</a></li>
                                    </ul>
            </li>
                        <li><a href="../parents/profile" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">Profile</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Select Child <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    <li><a href="../parents/select_a_child/50" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; line-height: 0.4px; !important">Annett Joy</a></li>

                    <li><a href="../parents/select_a_child/51" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; line-height: 0.4px; !important">Charlotte Pinkiewicz</a></li>
                                    </ul>
            </li>
                        <li><a href="../parents/change_password" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">Change Password</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../logout" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">Logout</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

QA NOT WORKING

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="../parents/dailyexperience" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">Daily Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../parents/attendance_records" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">Attendance Records</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../parents/photos" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">Photos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../parents/school_info" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">School Info</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">History <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="../parents/dailyexperience_history" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; line-height: 0.4px; !important">Daily Experience</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="../parents/attendance_records_history" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; line-height: 0.4px; !important">Attendance Records</a></li>
                                    </ul>
            </li>
                        <li><a href="../parents/profile" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">Profile</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Select Child <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    <li><a href="../parents/select_a_child/50" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; line-height: 0.4px; !important">Annett Joy</a></li>

                    <li><a href="../parents/select_a_child/51" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; line-height: 0.4px; !important">Charlotte Pinkiewicz</a></li>
                                    </ul>
            </li>
                        <li><a href="../parents/change_password" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">Change Password</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../logout" style="padding-top: 21px; padding-bottom: 11px; !important">Logout</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

This is a screenshot of my Network tab

[image]

Comment: what about JS ? Is there any changed, maybe different paths, minifacations?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is just fine in your code but I'm sure that your jQuery library doesn't loaded correctly. Make sure that jQuery script is included on the page as well as it present on specified path. Then it will work fine.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the demo of QA code after including jQuery reference.

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LeLLr/)**

Comment: the jsfiddle does not work it's not loading anything when i run the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap.js was getting loaded twice for some reason so i removed it once and it started working.

Comment: I have same problem, so basically you just removed the boostrap.js on your asset/javascripts/Bootstrap.js?